# Select a single row with minimum column value - sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, minimum

I have a table ZZZ with Columns A,B,C,D

I am selecting first X rows of table with column A desc.
Sqlite3 query would be

```
select * from ZZZ order by A desc limit X
```

How to select the row with minimum value of column B from the result of the above query.

In other words: 
I want the row with minimum value in column B from a table T.
This table T is generated by the query

```
select * from ZZZ order by A desc limit X
```

I am using Python sqlite3 interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do just that. Select the row with minimum value in column B from table T:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM ZZZ
    ORDER BY A DESC
    LIMIT X
) T
ORDER BY B ASC
LIMIT 1
```